# Using the Ratio Test to find interval of convergence

Tags: calculus

I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to use the ratio test once the I rewrite the form into lim of an+1/an.

For example I am given the series (x^k)/(4k+1)!

I rewrote it into lim as k-->infinity: [(x^(k+1))(4k+1)!]/[x^k(4k+2)!]

How can I get rid of (4k+1)! and (4k+2)!

Answer (score 2):

Your limit is not quite correct. Notice that you want to evaluate $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| =\lim_{k \to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{x^{k+1}}{[4(k+1)+1]!}}{\frac{x^{k}}{(4k+1)!}}\right| \\ =\lim_{k \to \infty}\left|\frac{x^{k+1}}{(4k+5)!}\cdot\frac{(4k+1)!}{x^{k}}\right| \\ = \lim_{k \to \infty}\left|\frac{x}{(4k+5)!}\cdot(4k+1)!\right|$$ Now make the substitution $$(4k+5)! = (4k+5)(4k+4)(4k+3)(4k+2)(4k+1)!$$ and see if you can evaluate the limit from there.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Comment: Did you need any more help? If not, please choose one of the three answers on here as the solution so that other users know this question is closed. You should do the same on the other two questions you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{(4k+1)!}{(4k+2)!} = \dfrac{1}{4k+2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{k+1}}{(4k+5)!}\cdot\frac{(4k+1)!}{x^k}\right|=|x|\frac1{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+4)(4k+5)}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$$

and your series converges for all $\;x\in\Bbb C\;$